# Referrer usage of Google Maps API-key

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is it possible to get to know the amount of API-requests per referrer when sharing an API-key?

We recently reached our Quota limit. We would like to find out which of the websites using that key made the most requests.

Comment: Technical support at Google can create such report for you. Reach them via https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support

Answer (score -1):

In the dashboard for your API connection, you can see from which IP address the requests were coming. That's the only way of checking where your API Keys are used from. Google doesn't (visibly) track from which site the requests origin. If you think your keys were used from unauthorized sources, contact Google for help.

Tip: Try to use a different API key for seperate websites. That way, your API Usage is easier to track. Google says (on [Best practices on using Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)) this is a best practise.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Maaike.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any mention of IP addresses of requests on the dashboard or any page linking to the API-key.